# jquery + lose focus of a textbox

Tags: jquery

I'm completely stuck.. I tried a few things. I want to lose the focus of a textbox when a user clicks on it.

I tried this:

```
$('.tagit-input[type=text]').focus(function(){
    $('.tagit-input[type=text]').blur();
});
```

as well as this, where I am giving the focus to a different text box instead:

```
$('.tagit-input[type=text]').focus(function(){
    $('.tagit[type=text]').focus();
});
```

as well as various methods in `keydown` etc. Is there something I'm missing? I'm just trying to lose focus of one box with a class `.tagit-input`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Does making the `input` in question `readonly` help at all?

Comment: I don't get it? You've just disabled the textbox as it now can't be focused? And it does seem to work just fine for me [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jESLD/) ....

Comment: Can't make it readonly, because I have other jQuery code running on it for tagging, but I don't want the user to be able to type in themselves. But readonly wasn't working.

Comment: Why not use a `<div>` or something, rather than a field in which the user is supposed to type?

Comment: I think readonly should still work. For instance, I have a date field where I want to force use of a datepicker, so I make it readonly. The datepicker can still fill it in.

Comment: Never mind, readonly worked for me. I was using a third party library, started reading their code and disabled a property they had there which was preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.focusout` http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 0):

If your only desire is to lose the focus of the element when focused-on, you can just trigger the [**.blur()**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) DOM event as the handler when the [**.focus()**](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) event is called **or** to select another element to focus, do the same and in addition, just trigger a focus on the desired element.

---

In your case all you would need to do to lose focus and select another element would be:

```
 $('.tagit-input[type=text]').focus(function(){
        $('.not-tagit-input[type=text]').focus();
    });
```

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/SxPt6/12/)